# Вывести числа float в строчку с тремя знаками после запятой

Tags: python, float

Есть код:

```py
def fl(df):
    return "%.3f" % df

num = [float(i) for i in input('Введите числа через пробел ').split()]

for j in range (len(num)):
    for i in range (len(num)-1):
        if abs(num[i])>abs(num[i+1]):
            a = num[i+1]
            num[i+1] = num[i]
            num[i] = a
        if abs(num[i]) == abs(num[i+1]) and num[i]>num[i+1]:
            b = num[i+1]
            num[i+1] = num[i]
            num[i] = b
for x in num:
    x = fl(x)
    print (x)
print(num)
print (" ".join(map(str, num)))
```

Нужно вывести список в строчку через пробел с тремя знаками после запятой. То есть вот так:
0.250 0.270 -1.000 1.000 3.000 -4.000 -5.000 5.000 8.000.
Что ни пробовал - получается либо в столбик, либо, как в моем коде, убираются цифры после запятой.

Comment: `print(" ".join(map(fl, num)))`

Comment: `print(' '.join(f'{x:.3f}' for x in num))`

Answer (score 0):

Можно указать `print`-у, что вам не нужно переносить на новую строку:

```
for x in num:
    x = fl(x)
    print(x, end=' ')  # В конце строки вывести пробел вместо переноса '\n'
```

По поводу однострочного варианта - можно в `map` передать вашу функцию `fl` вместо `str`
(из комментария `S. Nick`):

```
print(" ".join(map(fl, num)))
```